# Can't run the sample Project Tango app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-project-tango

Here's the code I am using:

```
git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java.git


    Cannot reload AVD list: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is 
not facet-valid with respect to enumeration[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi,
 xhdpi, 400dpi, xxdpi, 560dpi, xxxhdpi] it must be a value from the enumeration.
```

I get the following error non-stop when clicking on the run button. Any feedback is really appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the virtual device that you are trying to run it on?

Comment: @Khanal I am not sure what to select. It's my second day of having Tango dev kit so I am super newbee!

Comment: I am not familiar with the tango kit but based on the error and what I can see on the background, the issue seems to be on the avd, have you tried to run the wearable? Without any program to run, just run it?

Comment: Mona looks like the virtual device you are trying to run the app does not support the mentioned value of '280dpi'. Is there anyway you can try to edit it? I have been using genymotion, not sure if that has a wearable you can test or even if it helps but just a suggestion.

Comment: I am testing the AR demo @Khanal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that USB debugging is enabled on your Tango device, go to **Settings > About tablet > Build number** and then press Build number seven times. Then press back and go to **Developer options > USB debugging**.
Connect the tablet to your Mac. It will show up as a running device.

Comment: I'll accept this later when I check it with device. Thanks!

Comment: if you try the same example on the tablet it just errors: `failed to fit plane` can you please try `Java Augmented Reality Example` and let me know if that's the same for you? //it runs the app on the tablet though

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me.
The 'failed to fit plane' error shows up in case of measurement failure (insufficient depth points near click location).
Try to click on another clear luminous plane. @MonaJalal